# PayPal "cart upload" command done via server code

Tags: paypal, http-post, shopping-cart

My objective is to use a simple shopping cart to create a "cart upload" form which takes the user to a friendly PayPal page that handles shipping, taxes, etc based on the facilitator's account dashboard settings in which we can set those items. However I'd like to send the server-generated values of the cart-upload form via POST request to the paypal website https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr without showing the form on the client so that people won't tamper with the form values and set their prices.

When I perform the POST manually (submit the generated cart upload form), the Network tab of my dev console shows a request with ***"Provisional Headers shown"*** warning for a very short time, after which the request is 'updated' to show a bunch of things that I have no idea where they came from but are probably necessary for the success of this mission. The **Request Headers** suddenly fills up with the big **Cookie** field which contains among other things an "ectoken=...". This is an 'express-checkout' token, but how does it get there?
My idea is to do a POST via server request and to send these things in the header, or set the cookie properly so that when the request goes, it will put up the correct page I want.

When I perform the POST via the server code, it complains that my cookies are not enabled, etc. I started experimenting by putting some cookies gleaned from the http response of this POST, and it started to at least show different behavior such as showing me a "Session logged out" screen.

I now know there's lots to learn about how these requests go back & forth, but I believe if I can do this manually with the browser I should be able to do the same thing with server code? Just how does that "ectoken" (& the rest of the request header) get formulated puzzles me.

Comment: I suppose there was no way in PayPal to create the Cart Upload command securely, we ended up doing the hard-er way and using the whole tokens thing to do a whole bunch of extra stuff that this command would have solved.